# Loading a Windows Azure Project from Gallery into Visual Studio 2012

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, orchardcms, azure-web-app-service, webmatrix-2

I have a Windows Azure web site. I started this web site as a New -> Compute -> Web Site -> From Gallery. Once here, I chose the Orchard CMS. I have the site successfully running in Windows Azure. My challenge is, I want to do some customizations to it.

How do I get this code into my local Visual Studio 2012 instance so that I can:

1. Make customizations to the site with Visual Studio 2012.
2. Check it into source control so other on my team can work on it

I saw the following post: http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/installing-orchard-cms-as-an-azure-web-site. However, this only talks about opening the site in WebMatrix. I want to skip WebMatrix and go straight to Visual Studio if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use WebMatrix at all; another option is to just download the files from FTP and then create a VS solution and add the files you downloaded.

From Visual Studio you can easily deploy the solution to TFS and to your azure website.

As a side note, as of today (January 28th, 2014) the registry edit proposed by SilverNinja is no longer needed, I was able to open VS 2013 Professional from Webmatrix without editing the registry.

Answer (score 2):

[Download WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) and click the [Visual Studio button in the ribbon](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx). It must create a solution file for you to then access your website via Visual Studio. I don't have an Azure website at the moment to try it with.

---

You may need to [tweak the registry to get the VS 2012 to open properly](http://scribblebin.com/post/2012/09/13/WebMatrix-opens-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx):

- Type `regedit` and select the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.
- Locate `VisualStudio.DTE` and change the `CurVer` to
  `VisualStudio.DTE.11.0`
- Finally change the `CLSID` to `{059618E6-4639-4D1A-A248-1384E368D5C3}`

Comment: When I open the Remote Site in WebMatrix, the Visual Studio button is disabled :(.

Comment: Did you try [downloading your remote site first](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-download-a-remote-site-in-webmatrix)?

Comment: I downloaded the Remote Site. However, when I opened it in Visual Studio, and attempt to compile the project I get an error. The error says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ... Contrib.Cache.csproj" Why can't I compile the project? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user687554 "If you are going to use VS, please use the full source code version." ~ BertrandLeRoy on [CodePlex](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/456888).